# How to set og:image in Nuxt.js Nuxt/Content blog with images in content folders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

**How do I get a string representation of a deployed image's final location that I can supply to the og:image header code and have the og:header point to the correct url when deployed?**

I have a [website](https://www.brianssparetime.com) that is based on Nuxt.js and Nuxt Content.  To keep things organized, I have modified the usual nuxt set up so that I can bundle post .md files and the images they reference into a single folder, rather than keeping all images in a separate /static or /assets folder.  The site is deployed on netlify in static/generate mode.

When I share a post, I want services like reddit to select an appropriate thumbnail image, so I want to configure og:image headers on each post.

[Github code here](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog).  The posts are in [/content/posts](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/tree/master/content/posts), and I use the [v-img component](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/master/components/VImg.vue) in the markdown files to show images in that post's folder.

I've figured out how to add og:image headers this in the [slug file for posts](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/a752c7b25a4b738ff876f100458e75685e44f5d1/pages/posts/_slug.vue#L63):

```
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.post.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.post.description
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          property: 'og:image',
          content: 'https://brianssparetime.com/_nuxt/content' + this.post.dir + '/' + this.post.image
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

However, when the blog is deployed, this does not work because the deployed image link changes.  For example, in dev mode, `this.post.image` might point to pos_DSC01447.jpg, but in the deployed site, the image has been moved to pos_DSC01447.37e98b4.jpg where that additional bit changes with each deploy.  In the deployed version, `this.post.image` lacks this additional bit, leading to incorrect urls for og:image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved but davydnorris in this [github issue comment](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/106#issuecomment-935436874).  Answer is `content: 'https://www.brianssparetime.com' + require(\`@/content${this.post.dir}/${this.post.image}`)`